# PHP Multiply array() * integer

Tags: php, post, integer

My code is:

HTML part for POST:

```
<form action='key.php' method='POST'> 
<input type='number' name='consumervar[]' value='512'/>
<input type='number' name='consumervar[]' value='256'/>
<input type='number' name='consumervar[]' value='1024'/>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

PHP Code for key.php:

```
<?PHP
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $consumervar = $value*64;
  }
  print_r($consumervar); // this is for for debug (see array contents)
?>
```

BUt when i run everything it reproduces:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/blahblah/blahblah/key.php on line 3
```

Please help. How to do it correctly? It need to multiply every posted value with integer 64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the loop should be

```
foreach($_POST['consumervar'] as $key => $value) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as written, your code pulls out the ARRAY of consumervar values, which you try to multiply. You cannot "multiply" arrays in php.

As well, note that the $key/$value produced by the loop are simply copies of what exists in the array. You are not changing the array's values. For that, you should be doing

```
 $_POST['consumervar'][$key] = $value * 64;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $arr = isset($_POST['consumervar']) ? $_POST['consumervar'] : array();
    if(!is_array($arr)) die('some_error');

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$key] = $value*64;
    }
    print_r($arr); // this is for for debug (see array contents)
?>
```

The `$key` corresponds to the "name" in the `input` element in HTML.